# Google Sign In is failing only on (some) Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, google-signin

I am using `Google Sign In`  in my application. I am using google play services version `9.0.2`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
```

It was working fine for all devices, but now I am getting crash logs from Crashlytics and the crash is only happening on Xiaomi devices. Here are the crash logs.

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eterno/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0xffff4f45
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0xffff4f45
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1628)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2661)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1509)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3978)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3939)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
       at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

I am not able to reproduce the crash with any of the test devices that we can locally with us. Did any one else also face this issue with Xiaomi devices? Also, will upgrading the google play services version help in mitigating the issue?

P.S. I am not attaching code snippets which I wrote for Google Sign In because it is working for all other devices. This seems to be a specific problem related to Xiaomi devices.

Comment: This happen to my app too. Currently using Google Play Service v9.2.1.
I even send an compiled APK of Google offical Sign In app and it failed too. Any solutions?
Xiaomi MIUI indeed is very buggy. I used it before.

Comment: Take a look at this stats.. 100% crash with Xiaomi phone.
http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-02-16_at_8.18.27_PM.png

Comment: For me, it seems the return authentication result is null:
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out the playService App Version in device

Comment: We already are doing that check. If the google play services version is not compatible, then we prompt a dialog to update google play services.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem in my code. I found that release app is not working on those Xiaomi devices installed debug build.

I tried same release app without changing a single line of code on a different Xiaomi android phone and found app is working fine.

I didn't tried but this might be possible that resetting Xiaomi devices solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, it is not working only on some devices like Redmi Note 3 with Android OS 5.1 installed.

Comment: I am getting similar problem where sign-in works fine on debug build, but doesn't work on release build. Did you find a solution to that specific problem? Thanks.